# Using the Adobe Creative SDK without Creative Cloud?

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

Is it possible to use the Creative SDK for Android without being forced to use the Creative Cloud? If not, what are some good alternatives?

I took a look at the Fotor SDK, however unfortunately it seems that you can no longer download the SDK.

Comment: Did you get some solution? I want to remove footer "Creative Cloud Connected".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Creative SDK's Image Editor UI component, Creative Cloud login is not required for the core image editing tools.

Other components in the SDK, like the Asset Browser UI component and the Lightroom Photos API, work directly with Creative Cloud and therefore require user login.

[There is a guide for getting started with the Image Editor here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html).

Comment: Do I need to wait for the app approval (My app is SUBMITTED FOR REVIEW) or can I publish my app to the play store even if my key is still in DEVELOPMENT MODE? (Only using Editor UI without cloud)

Comment: You'll need to wait until it has been approved. If you haven't heard back, you can reach out at [help.creativesdk.com](http://help.creativesdk.com).